# CLUSTER SECURITY EXCEPTION in wildfly

Tags: jboss, cluster-computing, wildfly, session-replication

I configured wildfly in two system(master and slave) and able to control from central domain controller all the instances, but in my slave I am getting following exception

```
Server:server-four-slave] 06:32:05,826 ERROR [org.hornetq.core.server] (default I/O-1) HQ224018: Failed to create session: HornetQClusterSecurityException[errorType=CLUSTER_SECURITY_EXCEPTION message=HQ119099: Unable to authenticate cluster user: HORNETQ.CLUSTER.ADMIN.USER]
```

And session are not replicated in my slave instances but session replication is working properly in all instances of master host.. can you please suggest me whats going wrong do I need to do any special configuration?

FYI... We have set cluster password for `<hornetq-server>`

Comment: any one have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Just for others not to be disappointed with this dead tread:
Ensure to base64 encode the password